# Junit - how to get test result as string?

Tags: kotlin, junit

I am trying to test the code and get a result as String to send it to API later.

```
class FirstClass{
    fun main(){
        print("Hello world!")
    }
}
```

Test:

```
ort org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.io.PrintStream
import kotlin.test.assertEquals


internal class FirstClassTest {

    private val outContent = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    private val errContent = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    private val originalOut = System.out
    private val originalErr = System.err

    @BeforeEach
    fun setUp() {
        System.setOut(PrintStream(outContent))
        System.setErr(PrintStream(errContent))
    }

    @AfterEach
    fun tearDown() {
        System.setOut(originalOut)
        System.setErr(originalErr)
    }

    @Test
    fun main() {
        val SUT = FirstClass()
        SUT.main()
        val testResult = assertEquals("Hello world!", outContent.toString())
        print("Test result: $testResult")
        val api = Api()
        val apiResult = api.sendResult(testResult.toString())
        print("Api result: $apiResult")
    }

}
```

The test is passing, however, I do not see printed messages. How to get a test result as String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues here.  The main one is:

#### The redirection affects your test method too.

Because you've redirected `System.out`, the `print()` in your test method goes to `outContent`, along with the output from `FirstClass.main()` that you want to test, instead of to the screen or wherever you want it.

I can see two fixes for this.

The quick one is for your test method to **output to `originalOut`**:

```
originalOut.print("Test result: $testResult")
```

Your test method is in the class which does the redirection, so there's no problem with it knowing about the redirection, and it already has access to `originalOut`.

However, if you can, I think a better solution is to **refactor `FirstClass` so that it doesn't hard-code the stream** it writes to.  For example, the stream could be passed as a parameter; or it could return the string directly (and the caller, in a thin non-tested wrapper, could write it to `System.out`).

That would be more work, but would make your code more flexible as well as easier to test.

Other issues include:

#### You're using `print()` instead of `println()`.

Many streams are line-buffered, writing their output only after a newline, and so you might not see any results if there isn't one.  (And even if you do, all the results would be jammed on a single line!)

#### You assign the result of `assertEquals()`.

`assertEquals()` doesn't have a useful return value.  (It return `Unit`.)  So your code will simply show:

```
Test result: kotlin.Unit
```

Instead, like all the `assert` functions, it throws an exception if the assertion fails.  So there's no point in storing or processing the return value; simply calling the assertion is enough.

— This means that there's usually no need to call `print()`/`println()` from your test method anyway!  If there's a failure, it'll be obvious: running from the command line will stop with an exception message and stack trace; IntelliJ shows a big red mark next to that test; Maven and Gradle will stop the build (after all tests have run), showing the number of failures.  So if everything continues smoothly, you know the tests have passed.

#### `Api` is not defined.

The code you posted above won't compile, because it doesn't include a definition or import for `Api`.  (Those last lines can be removed, though, without affecting the question.)

#### `main()` is a confusing name for a test.

The unit testing framework will find and run all test methods annotated with `@Test`.  A test class will often contain many different test methods, and it's usual to name them after the aspect they're testing.  (That makes any failures clearer.)  Calling it `main()` not only fails to describe what's being tested, but also suggests that the method will be run from outside the testing framework, which would probably not behave properly.